# How to know which user killed a process

Tags: linux, logging, process, users, kill

Is there a way in linux to find out which user or which process killed another process? Maybe a log?

I searched through `/var/log` and specifically on `auth.log.*` but I didn't find anything interesting..

I suppose that the process was killed using `htop` but as far as I know it doesn't keep activities logs.

Thanks

Comment: why downvote? comment please..

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but if you mouseover the downvote button, you'll see the popup "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful". Downvotes without a given reason may be assumed to be for that one.

Comment: I don't know how does it seem unclear or not useful. Regarding research effort I only found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why

Comment: Telling us what you've already done to research the issue **in your original posting** is useful, since it avoids us wasting our time retreading ground you've already covered.  I can't comment on whether or not the downvote was fair, since I didn't make it.  You asked what a downvote without a comment means, and I told you; it's probably not worth getting defensive about.

Answer (score 1):

Without some form of auditing enabled, it's not possible to find out as far as I know.

There are some useful docs on Audit Control here (other distros will also find this useful): http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html

Specifically (untested):

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S all
```

Should have the desired effect providing the audit system is set up correctly.

Christian.